# Construct cv::Mat from two cv::Mat's and a mask

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two (same size, same type) `cv:Mat`'s let us call them **A,B**. I have also another `cv::Mat` which is a mask (0 and 1 values or whatever, 0 and 255 applicable also) let us call it **M**.

I need to construct a new `cv::Mat` (**C**) that has the same type and size of the **A** and **B**. The values of the **C** `cv::Mat` is as follow:

```
C(x,y) = A(x,y) if  M(x,y)==1
C(x,y) = B(x,y) if M(x,y)==0
```

The simple solution I am doing right now is to iterate over the **M** and branching its value and assigning to **C** the correct value. However, is there some better approach? Ready and optimised one from OpenCV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to do it in two steps:

```
cv::Mat C(A.rows, A.cols, A.type());
// copy A in C where M != 0
A.copyTo(C, M);
// copy B in C where M == 0
B.copyTo(C, 255 - M);
```

**Edit:**

Has Micka pointed out for better performance

```
// start from B
cv::Mat C = B.clone();

// copy B in C where M == 0
A.copyTo(C, M);
```

Comment: this should be the most simple and best readable solution. Not sure whether it is faster to loop over whole mask manually, however. MIght depend on image sizes, build setting, etc. Maybe important to note that OpenCV masks will only decide between 0 and non-0, so C will be filled with everything from A where M is non-0, so no matter whether it is 1, 255, 103 or a mix of these within the mask.